# Multiple MM selects related to 1 MM table

Tags: typo3

I've currently got an issue where I'm trying to make it so a Typo3 form has multiple multi-select fields that can modify the same MM table. When a user saves the form, only the info in the last multi-select field is saved, resulting in the previous multi-select fields being empty. Below is what I have at the moment (with placeholders instead of actual table names etc):

```
'[FIELD A]' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => '[FIELD A]',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => '[FOREIGN TABLE]',
        'foreign_table_where' => ' AND category = "CAT1"',
        'size' => 10,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 99
    )
),
'[FIELD B]' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => '[FIELD B]',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => '[FOREIGN TABLE]',
        'MM' => '[MM TABLE]',
        'foreign_table_where' => ' AND category = "CAT2"',
        'size' => 10,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 99
    )
),
'[FIELD C]' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => '[FIELD C]',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => '[FOREIGN TABLE]',
        'MM' => '[MM TABLE]',
        'foreign_table_where' => ' AND category = "CAT3"',
        'size' => 10,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 99
    )
),
'[FIELD D]' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => '[FIELD D]',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => '[FOREIGN TABLE]',
        'MM' => '[MM TABLE]',
        'foreign_table_where' => ' AND category = "CAT4"',
        'size' => 10,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 99
    )
),
```

To elaborate, when I save the Typo3 form, only the information in [FIELD D] is saved, and any existing data from the other 3 fields is removed. I'd need it so the data from all fields are saved.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your MM table is that the DataHandler does not accept the MM table for multiple fields because it needs one more information. You should add a field "fieldname" to your MM table:

`fieldname varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,`

Then in the config of each field add a configuration to make the DataHandler know which fieldname to store in each MM record relation. Example for FIELD A:

```
'[FIELD A]' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => '[FIELD A]',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => '[FOREIGN TABLE]',
        'MM' => '[MM TABLE]',
        'MM_match_fields' => [
            'fieldname' => 'FIELD A'
        ],
        'size' => 10,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 99
    ]
],
```

By this way you can also add an additional field about the "tablename" of the records relation. This allows you to use one MM table for multiple tables, too. 
Check out the table sys_category_record_mm which does the same.

Comment: Looks like this was the thing! Thank you!